# ASP.NET SQL Membership Tables

Tags: asp.net, sqlmembershipprovider

What's the best way to tie my tables (like Customer, Orders) to the Users in the membership tables. Is there a way to tie it using an int somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `User.ProviderUserKey` but that is a GUID, not an int.  That will map to the UserId field in the aspnet_Membership table